# How to pass arguments to twoClassSummary in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying something very simple: make a function call to `twoClassSummary` in `caret` package.

**A reprex**

```
library(caret)

pred <- runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1)
obs <- rbinom(1000, size = 1, prob = pred)

twoClassSummary(
  data = data.frame(
    obs = obs,
    pred = pred
  )
)
```

This gives the following error:

> Error in auc_(actual, predicted) :    Not compatible with requested
>   type: [type=list; target=double].

**What I know**

I've looked at the documentation for `twoClassSummary` but that seems very unclear. Most of it is focused on use within a call to `trainControl`

Most of all I just want to know what the documentation should really have stated more clearly:

- What should the argument `data` look like?
- What should other arguments look like? Do I even need those or are they optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twoClassSummary` requires a data frame of four columns:

column named as level 1 of response class with the corresponding predicted probability  ("Y" in this case):

```
set.seed(1)
Y <- runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1)
```

obs - true labels:

```
obs <- rbinom(1000, size = 1, prob = Y)
obs <- factor(ifelse(obs == 1, "Y", "N"))
```

column named as level 2 of response class with the corresponding predicted probability ("N" in this case):

```
 N <- 1 - Y
```

pred - predicted labels (using the default threshold of 0.5):

```
pred <- ifelse(Y > 0.5, "Y", "N")
```

and now:

```
twoClassSummary(
  data = data.frame(obs = obs,
                    pred = pred,
                    Y = Y, 
                    N = N),
  lev = levels(obs))
```

output:

```
      ROC      Sens      Spec 
0.8253911 0.7529183 0.7263374
```